# Caliburn.Micro, SelectedItem does not trigger on EditableCombobox when Non-Existing item is being typed

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am trying to set a CanExecute method as soon as a user types information in a ComboBox with a bound list of items. I can disnable the button with CanAddCustomer (name is AddCustomer) without issues when there is an existing item selected; Disableling the button works as well when the input is empty (selectedCustomer is null); but these events do not seem to pickup free typing in the input box

[image: Empty, Disabled]

[image: Existing customer, Disabled]

[image: Non existing item, should Enable]

1. Disabled Because empty,
2. Disabled because Existing customer
3. Should be enabled, because non existent entry

the WPF for the combobox

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="Customers" Height="40"
    DisplayMemberPath="CustomerName"
    Controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="False"
    Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Select a Customer"
    IsEditable="True"
    MaxDropDownHeight="125"
    Margin="0 0 15 0"
    Grid.Column="0" 
/>
```

The data in the ViewModel:

```
private Customer _selectedCustomer ;
private string _customer;

public string Customer
{
    get { return _customer; }
    set {
        _customer = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanAddCustomer);
    }
} 


public Customer SelectedCustomer 
{
    get { return _selectedCustomer; }
    set {
        _selectedCustomer = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanAddCustomer);
        GetAllOrdersPerCustomer();
    }
}


public bool CanAddCustomer
{
    get
    {
        Customer cs = SelectedCustomer;
        if (cs == null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Customer))
        {
            return false;
        } else if (cs != null ) {
            return false;
        } else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

} 

public void AddCustomer()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("You cliked");
}
```

the issue is known to me, when I debug the project, I can see that "SelectedCustomer" is not triggered...
but.. how do I then reference the text in the textbox?
The `public string Customer` property was my attempt at that, but this is only the value of a selectedItem

Comment: The source property isn't set when the typed in text cannot be mapped to a value in the `ItemsSource`. What should it be set to?

Comment: preferably to a value that I can then pass into the next window.. how would I do that?

Comment: The `SelectedItem` can only set to a value that's in the `ItemsSource`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ComboBox` control sets its `SelectedItem` property to `null` when you type in a value that is not present in its `ItemsSource`.

You have implemented your view model to indeed enable the `ComboBox` when `SelectedItem` is null and the `ComboBox` is empty.

Maybe you're better off binding to the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` in this case. It should return whatever that's currently in the `TextBox`.

The `SelectedItem` property can only set to a value that's in the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why it doesnt function the way I thought it should; I've accepted an answer explaining how to solve it as well

Comment: semi.. still learning and Caliburn is taking a big load of that steep learning curve away
I can't accept both your answers, both both deserve an upvote at least

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the property of Text in ComboBox and then bind it to your property.

```
 <ComboBox 
     x:Name="Customers" Height="40"
     Text="{Binding Customer, Mode=TwoWay}"
     DisplayMemberPath="CustomerName"
     Controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="False"
     Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Select a Customer"
     IsEditable="True"
     MaxDropDownHeight="125"
     Margin="0 0 15 0"
     Grid.Column="0" 
 />
```

Comment: Thank you! This is all I needed to do!